# How to reset codeigniter alternator() function

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, alternator

How do I set an alternator to its inicial position?

**Code:**

```
foreach($items as $item):
        foreach($sides as $side):
            echo alternator('Left', 'Right');
        endforeach;
        //I want the alternator to "restart" here and always start from the initial variable "Left" in this case
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Note: To use multiple separate calls to this function simply call the function with no arguments to re-initialize.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/string_helper.html)

```
foreach($items as $item):
        foreach($sides as $side):
            echo alternator('Left', 'Right');
        endforeach;
        alternator();
endforeach;
```